# Time sleep in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I try to use `time.sleep` in Web2py. Let's say, if I want a text to appear 5 seconds after an other text.

In the Controller:

```
import time

def time_test():
    t = time.sleep(5)
    return locals()
```

In the View:

```
<h1>Text 1</h1>
{{=t}}
<h1>Text 2</h1>
```

But this just makes the page load 5 seconds later.

In Python it works like this:

```
import time
print "Image 1"
time.sleep(5)
print "Image 2"
```

but I would like to learn how to do this in Web2py

Comment: HTML delivered over HTTP just doesn't work that way. For one, you're just blocking the *template rendering* server side with this approach. But even if you were to delay sending the response between those HTML tags it's unlikely browsers would actually render it that way - they usually start rendering pretty late and in a hard to predict way, because e.g. there could be a `document.write()` coming later.

Comment: If you were to send a `text/plain` streaming response, you can achieve that effect as long as you pay attention to a couple details. But with HTML you'd need to go the AJAX route and deliver some JS that fetches and displays those messages later.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can do this the way like Lukas Graf said but if it's just a matter of showing text with a five second delay in a web2py page, then you don't really need the web2py functionality for it. You can just use a client side script like javascript. You render a page with web2py including a javascript that will show a certain text with a 5 second delay. This is the more standard way to achieve this, web2py or not.